# jquery multiple infinite animations

Tags: jquery, animation

I have 3 elements on my page that i need to animate infinitely. Animations do work, but the problem is memory leak. I've tried in few ways to solve this but i didn't succeed. My page withstands for about 3 minutes and then it blows, when memory using reaches about 100Mb (i've checked this with Google Chrome's Developer tools - timeline memory record)

Here is the jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".shiner")
    .repeat()
    .delay(1000)
    .animate({'marginLeft': '-100px'}, 1400)
    .animate({'marginLeft': '170px' }, 1400)
    .delay(1500)
    .wait(0);
$("h1")
    .repeat()
    .animate({'marginLeft': '8px'}, 1000)
    .delay(3300)
    .animate({'opacity': 0}, 1000)
    .animate({'marginLeft': '-300px'}, 0)
    .animate({'opacity': 1}, 0)
    .wait(0);
$(".slogan")
    .repeat()
    .animate({'marginRight': '160px'}, 1000)
    .delay(3300)
    .animate({'opacity': 0}, 1000)
    .animate({'marginRight': '0px'}, 0)
    .animate({'opacity': 1}, 0)
    .wait(0);
});
```

So, how to prevent memory leaking? These functions are quite simple and should not consume a lot of memory i guess...

PS I've used [jquery-timing](http://creativecouple.github.io/jquery-timing/) plugin in order to make this animations infinite.

Comment: You should rather report this as an issue to the creators of the plugin instead of trying to find a "solution". It's a bug. Nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: I also suggest to take a look at CSS animations http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Comment: Thanks, but is there any other proper way to make this animation without memory leaking regardless of this plugin?